# Can't set a cross subdomain cookie in Django

Tags: django, cookies, cross-domain

I'm trying to use a subdomain cross site cookie with django but I cannot get it, I am in a valid subdomain but it doesn't seems to be useful.

Thie is my conf:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.ngrok.io'
```

This is the headers from the browser:
[image: headers]

But I get the message:

> This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url

How can I do to make it work?

Comment: You are trying to set a cookie for a different domain than the one of your website. If that is your local environment you could just leave `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` empty in your local settings.

Comment: Is an auth domain for other apps domains

Comment: What is the current full URL you are accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As says in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) there is a newer specification for cookies ([RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)). The old specification can let you share a cookie sent it from a subdomain "`sub.domain.com`" or "`domain.com`" with `domain=.domain.com` to share between domains and subdomains, but the newer specification can let you share by domain and subdomain only if you sent the cookie from "`domain.com`" with `SameSite=None` and `domain=domain.com`